# The resource identified by this request is able to generate responses only with features incompatible with the "accept" directive

Tags: spring, rest

I want to make a rest webservice call :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("stock")
public class StockController {

    @Autowired
    private StockService stockService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/TOM", produces = "application/json")
    public JsonModel getByLocAndItm(@RequestParam(required=false) String LOC, @RequestParam(required=false) String ITM) {
        JsonModel jsonModel = new JsonModel();
        List<com.java.oxalys.beans.Stock> stock = stockService.getByLocAndItm(LOC.split("|"), null);
        jsonModel.setDatas(stock);
        return jsonModel;
    }

}
```

service :

```
@Service
public class StockServiceImpl implements StockService {

    @Autowired
    private StockDao stockDao;

    @Override
    public List<com.java.oxalys.beans.Stock> getByLocAndItm(String[] locs, String[] itms) {
        return stockDao.getByLocAndItm(locs, itms);
    }

}
```

DAO :

```
@Repository
public class StockDaoImpl implements StockDao {

    @Override
    public List<Stock> getByLocAndItm(String[] locs, String[] itms) {

        List<Stock> ret = new ArrayList<Stock>();

        String where = "";

        String where_locs = "", sep_locs = "";
        for(String loc : locs) {
            where_locs += sep_locs + " s.LOC_0 = '" + loc + "'";
            sep_locs = " or ";
        }
        where_locs = "(" + where_locs + ")";
        where = where_locs;

        Stock tmp = new Stock();
        tmp.setLoc("eto");
        tmp.setItmoxa(where);
        ret.add(tmp);
        return ret;

    }

}
```

At runtime with **postman** : `localhost:8080/Oxalys_WS/stock/TOM?LOC=BOQSCM171L` then I get error `The resource identified by this request is able to generate responses only with features incompatible with the "accept" directive present in the request header`

So what is wrong ?

Comment: What is Postman sending as the Accept header? Try sending the header `Accept: application/json` with your Postman request and see if that fixes it.

Comment: always the same error !

Comment: Can you provide the complete request (including all headers) and response?

Comment: Check your path parameters, if you have /stock instead of just stock.

Comment: request is `localhost:8080/Oxalys_WS/stock/TOM?LOC=BOQSCM171L` , headers are `Server →Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type →text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language →fr
Content-Length →1153
Date →Tue, 19 Feb 2019 14:30:35 GMT` and `Accept : application/json`